# MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM always the same

Tags: php, security, encryption, cryptography, blowfish

I'm using `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` and `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` as part of blowfish encryption, but I'm noticing it outputs the same random digit every time. It differs from machine to machine, but it's the same in each machine.

- Is this normal?
- Does it affect the strength of the initialization vector (IV) I generate with it?

Comment: Are you seeding the random number generator before using this any of the randome number generation functions/processes such as mcrypt_create_iv()? And if so, are you using the same seed each time?

Comment: Are you testing this on a Windows server; and if so, what version PHP are you using?

Comment: How are you using it? Please post a small example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Please, reveal the mystery how did you manage to break prng.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're using Windows and that your PHP version is older than 5.3

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php: PHP 5.3.0: "MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM and MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM became available on Windows platforms."

To answer your questions:

- **Is this normal?** *It is a known condition for older PHP versions in Windows. Otherwise, no.*
- **Does it affect the strength of the initialization vector (IV) I generate with it?** *Yes, it does. Your IVs MUST be unique for each encryption.*